# Grease Pencil Layers/Keyframes not showing up in Dope sheet

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil, dopesheet

I'm fairly new to blender and I've been working on a Grease pencil animation for the past couple weeks and everything has been fine until recently when I couldn't see the keyframes i was creating for my Gpencil object.

They are still being recorded and playing out however, I can not see or edit them. In the dope sheet and timeline I cant see the layers I have inside my Gpecil object either. Only the keyframes I've made for the position, rotation, scale, etc are displayed. I've tried most solutions and I can't seem to figure what is going wrong, any help is appreciated[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the exchange. This could be caused by a number of things. Firstly the Timeline module will only show location, rotation and scale of your grease pencil object, not the gp frames. Have you changed the Timeline window to Dope Sheet (by clicking on the clock in the top corner of the module) and the selected Grease Pencil and then selected the object again?